# How to change time zone in Flurry Analytics

Tags: flurry-analytics

Flurry analytic default time zone is PDT . I am not able to change it into IST. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2):

All time zones in Flurry use pacific standard time by design and the timezone can not be changed. One notable exception is the "Time of Day" metric which shows the metrics based upon the end users time zone.

The documentation for this feature may be found here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/timeofday/

Comment: Time of Day gives data only for today. How to convert past data into my time zone

Comment: There is not a way to change the timezone built into the Flurry UI. You can download data using one of the APIs and change the timezone within your script though. See here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/

Comment: Another exception seems to be the "Real time dashboard" - when I go there the time is shown in my time zone and not in PST.

Comment: Is it still impossible, as of today, to pick a timezone when querying metrics? It seems a little bit weird to me that we can only fetch data grouped by days in PDT timezone, which mean nothing to those living in Europe for example (approximately 9 hours of difference, for western Europe).